CupertinoSLiverRefresh is not workign with SuperScaffold
as i have mentioned on the title, i have tried many ways to use the CupertinoSliverRefreshControl to work along with the superscaffold, but never successfull.
body: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: [
          CupertinoSliverRefreshControl(
            onRefresh: () {
              print("refreshing ...");
              return ref.refresh(skillsProvider.future);
            },
            // child: EasyRefresh(
            //   child: myPagedListView(ref),
            // ),
          ),
          SliverFillRemaining(
            child: myPagedListView(ref),
          )
        ],
      ),

to resolve this problem, give me a workign example

Yes i did that. it works, but i still have some issues. `body:
CustomScrollView(
        primary: false,
        physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(
          parent: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        ),
        slivers: [
          CupertinoSliverRefreshControl(
            onRefresh: () {
              print("refreshing ...");
              return ref.refresh(skillsProvider.future);
            },
          ),
          SliverFillRemaining(
            fillOverscroll: true,
            child: myPagedListView(ref),
          ),
        ],
      ), 

Widget myPagedListView(WidgetRef ref) {
        final pagingController =
            ref.watch(skillsProvider.notifier).pagingController;
        return PagedListView<int, Skill>(
          pagingController: pagingController,
          physics:
              const BouncingScrollPhysics(), 
          builderDelegate: PagedChildBuilderDelegate<Skill>(
            itemBuilder: (context, item, index) {
              return SkillCard(item);
            },
            firstPageErrorIndicatorBuilder: (context) =>
                const CupertinoActivityIndicator(),
            firstPageProgressIndicatorBuilder: (context) =>
                const CupertinoActivityIndicator(),
            newPageProgressIndicatorBuilder: (context) =>
                const CupertinoActivityIndicator(),
          ),
        );
      }

` since PagedListView a scrollable, when i add the physics eventhough the refreshindicator works, I cannot scroll the myPagedListView widgets.

Try adding physics

body: CustomScrollView(
  physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(
    parent: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
  ),
  slivers: [
    CupertinoSliverRefreshControl(
      onRefresh: () async {
        print("refreshing ...");
        await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2)); //your future should be have some delay 
        return Future.value();
      },
    ),
  ],
),
);


Thank you. since PagedListView a scrollable, when i add the physics eventhough the refreshindicator works, I cannot scroll the myPagedListView widgets.
